# How do I give a specific link to an iframe with the same index?

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling to create a function where the "src" of multiple iframes is replaced with another link from a list of links.

**HTML**

```
<p class="yt-link">https://www.youtube.com/embed/xJVwvq5z3MI</p>
<p class="yt-link">https://www.youtube.com/embed/qWwb8S02f_c</p>
<p class="yt-link">https://www.youtube.com/embed/TiC8pig6PGE</p>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R9Xpr9XJzGI?"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R9Xpr9XJzGI?"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R9Xpr9XJzGI?"></iframe>
```

**Javascript** (My third approach)

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.yt-links');
let frame = document.querySelector('iframe');

function changeLink() {
  links.forEach((a, i) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      if (a.textContent == "") {

      } else {
        frame.src = "";
        frame.removeAttribute('src');
        frame.src = a.textContent;
      }
      frame = frame.nextElementSibling;
    }
  });
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xJVwvq5z3MI"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qWwb8S02f_c"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TiC8pig6PGE"></iframe>
```

I'm relatively new to JavaScript - have mercy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i did understand you correctly, that's should help.

Note: you have spelt **the class name** wrong at **links**.

The best practise is to work with [data-value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.yt-link');
const frame = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

links.forEach((link, i) => frame[i].src = link.textContent);
```

**Edit:**
If you to check if the link exist.

```
links.forEach((link, i) => (link.textContent) ? frame[i].src = link.textContent : null);
```

**Edit 2:**
If you don't want to use arrow function.

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.yt-link');
const frame = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

links.forEach(function(link, i) {
  if (link.textContent) {
    frame[i].src = link.textContent
  }
});
```

**Edit 3:** make sure that the **iframe elmenent** is exits by adding **frame[i]** in the condition.

```
links.forEach(function(link, i) {
  if (link.textContent && frame[i]) {
    frame[i].src = link.textContent
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to nest another `for` loop inside your `forEach` loop. You can simply use `document.querySelectorAll('iframe')` and use access them by the `i` index you've passed in. Also, you do not have the class `.yt-links`, but `.yt-link`, so fix that typo and you're good to go:

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.yt-link');
let frame = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

function changeLink() {
  links.forEach((a, i) => {
    if (a.textContent == "") {

    } else {
      frame[i].src = "";
      frame[i].removeAttribute('src');
      frame[i].src = a.textContent;
    }
  });
}

changeLink();
```

```html
<p class="yt-link">https://www.youtube.com/embed/xJVwvq5z3MI</p>
<p class="yt-link">https://www.youtube.com/embed/qWwb8S02f_c</p>
<p class="yt-link">https://www.youtube.com/embed/TiC8pig6PGE</p>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R9Xpr9XJzGI?"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R9Xpr9XJzGI?"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/R9Xpr9XJzGI?"></iframe>
```